# How do I know when I should use ObjectManager's create() or get()?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, object-manager

I understand that I can create an object using the `ObjectManager` through either its `get()` or `create()` method.

From the docs, `create()` will always create a new instance whereas `get()` retrieves a cached version of an object instance.

My chain of thoughts are:

- I wouldn't know whether an object has already been created somewhere
  else in the cache, would I?
- If I don't know whether an object is    already in the cache, how do
  I know when I should use `create()` or    `get()` method when
  creating an object? Will I end up creating multiple objects?
- One possible use of `get()` I    can think of is for singleton      classes as they don't need to be    created again. However, being new
  to Magento2, how would I know    whether an object I want to create     is an singleton or not? Similarly, will I end up creating multiple objects?

Comment: Use as much as possible dependency injection (DI) and avoid object manager. And use factories or proxy. The oject manager is use for the bootstrapping process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectManager **get()**:

Used for a **singleton object**, when you want to use previously set object through out the code you can use get().

ObjectManager **create()**;

create() will create each time a new object.

So, as per your requirements you can use get() or create().

Ex. if you want to use quote data you need to use old object so you can use get() and when you want to use your custom model and save data you can use create().

You can share code model's object with get().

Comment: Will I come to a situation where an object could already be created elsewhere but I don't know about it and need to check whether that object is already cached before I know I should use create() or get()?

Comment: if you are using core model than you can use get() even if will not get any value you will have an object so you can setdata in that object